# Load DataTable data to a Edit Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, yajra-datatable

I am trying to create an edit function for my data table. The data table is created using Yajra Data tables. Everything working fine unless when I try to load existing data into the edit modal it fails. No error is showing but the modal does not launch. I have only included a little portion of my code here for easy reference.

Modal:

```
<!-- Update Status Model Box -->
    <div id="updateStatusModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content bg-default">                
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" id="updateStatus">
                        @csrf
                        @method('PUT')
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <div class="form-group text-center">
                                    <h6 class="font-weight-bold">Stage 1</h6>
                                    <label for="stage_1" class="switch">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="stage_1">
                                        <div class="slider round"></div>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>                            

                        </div>

                        <div class="row">                            

                            <div class="col">

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md">
                                        <label for="firstname">Coding</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" value="" placeholder="Enter Completed Page Count">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
                    <button type="button" name="update_btn" id="update_btn" class="btn btn-outline-warning">Update</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

jquery funtion:

```
// Edit action
    $(document).on('click', '.updateStatus', function(){


        $tr = $(this).closest('tr');

        var data = $tr.clidren("td").map(function(){
            return $(this).text();
        }).get();

        console.log(data);

        $('#id').val(data[0]);
        $('#job_id').val(data[2]);
        $('#stage_1').val(data[3]);
        $('#conversion').val(data[4]);     

        $('#updateStatusModal').modal('show');

    });
```

I tried this method I found but this is not working. Can anyone provide me any pointers here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just didn't seen your front scripts (also back-end codes), but instead I can share my implementation for that you need. It works perfectly like showed in [this (screenshot)](https://www.screencast.com/t/9EsVUIJGvXM).
Here I'll put front and back codes. There is functionality for editing existsing Datatable record, also record deletion.

**FRONT**

```
<!--HERE ATTACH NECESSARY STYLES-->

<!--VIEW end-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/admin/datatables.min.css') }}"/>
<table id="yajra_datatable" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Options</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<div class="modal modal-danger fade" id="modal_delete">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Language</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Are You sure You want to delete this Language?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button id="delete_action" type="button" class="btn btn-outline">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal modal-warning fade" id="modal_edit">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Language</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="language_name">Language Name</label>
                    <input name="language_name" id="language_name" type="text" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Language Name">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button id="edit_action" type="button" class="btn btn-outline">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="item_id" value="0" />
<!--VIEW end-->

<!--HERE ATTACH NECESSARY SCRIPTS-->

<!--SCRIPTS start-->
<script src="{{ asset('js/admin/jquery.dataTables.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var YajraDataTable;
    function delete_action(item_id){
        $('#item_id').val(item_id);
    }
    function edit_action(this_el, item_id){
        $('#item_id').val(item_id);
        var tr_el = this_el.closest('tr');
        var row = YajraDataTable.row(tr_el);
        var row_data = row.data();
        $('#language_name').val(row_data.name);
    }
    function initDataTable() {
        YajraDataTable = $('#yajra_datatable').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": "{{ route('admin.book_languages.ajax') }}",
            "columns":[
                {
                    "data": "name",
                    "name": "name",
                },
                {
                    "data": "",
                    "name": ""
                },
            ],
            "autoWidth": false,
            'columnDefs': [
                {
                    'targets': -1,
                    'defaultContent': '-',
                    'searchable': false,
                    'orderable': false,
                    'width': '10%',
                    'className': 'dt-body-center',
                    'render': function (data, type, full_row, meta){
                        return '<div style="display:block">' +
                            '<button onclick="delete_action(' + full_row.id + ')" type="button" class="delete_action btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_delete" style="margin:3px"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i> Delete</button>' +
                            '<button onclick="edit_action(this, ' + full_row.id + ')" type="button" class="edit_action btn btn-warning btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_edit" style="margin:3px"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</button>' +
                            '</div>';
                    }

                }
            ],
        });
        return YajraDataTable;
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var YajraDataTable = initDataTable();
        $('#delete_action').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ route('admin.book_languages.delete') }}",
                data: {
                    'item_id': $('#item_id').val(),
                    '_token': "{{ csrf_token() }}"
                },
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#modal_delete').modal('hide');
                    YajraDataTable.ajax.reload(null, false);
                    console.log(data.message);
                }
            })
        });
        $('#edit_action').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ route('admin.book_languages.edit') }}",
                data: {
                    'item_id': $('#item_id').val(),
                    'language_name': $('#language_name').val(),
                    '_token': "{{ csrf_token() }}"
                },
                type: "POST",
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#modal_edit').modal('hide');
                    YajraDataTable.ajax.reload(null, false);
                    console.log(data.message);
                }
            })
        });
        $('#modal_delete').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            $('#item_id').val(0);
        });
        $('#modal_edit').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            $('#item_id').val(0);
            $('#language_name').val("");
        });
    });
</script>
<!--SCRIPTS end-->
```

**BACK**

```
public function index() {
    return view('admin.book-languages.index');
}
public function ajax() {
    $items = BookLanguage::latest('id');
    return DataTables::of($items)->make(true);
}
public function delete(Request $request) {
    $item_id = $request->get('item_id');
    $item = BookLanguage::find($item_id);
    if(empty($item)) {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'Item not found!',
        ], 200); // 404
    } else {
        $item->delete();
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'Item successfully deleted.',
        ], 200);
    }
}
public function update(Request $request) {
    $item_id = $request->get('item_id');
    $item = BookLanguage::find($item_id);
    if(empty($item)) {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'Item not found!',
        ], 404);
    } else {
        $item->name = $request->get('language_name');
        $item->save();
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'Item successfully updated.',
        ], 200);
    }
}
```

**ROUTES**

```
// ...
// book_languages
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'book-languages', 'as' => 'admin.book_languages.',], function () {
        Route::get('all', 'BookLanguageController@index')->name('index');
        Route::get('ajax', 'BookLanguageController@ajax')->name('ajax');
        Route::post('update', 'BookLanguageController@update')->name('edit');
        Route::post('delete', 'BookLanguageController@delete')->name('delete');
    });
// ...
```

I think this can help you and others to build wanted functionality. Here this could be also with more hint-comments, but as it not small, I can answer later via post comments.

Answer (score 0):

i am building a Laravel ERP-like web application and am implementing a CRUD function modal like you. I have made mine a server-side processing application with resource APIs in Laravel. Well, please be reminded that i have cut the @extends(layout.app) & @section('stylesheet') parts to go right into the answer. You should extend them in your own application to make everything work.

View.blade script

```
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    }
                });

    var table = $('#customertable').DataTable({
                    processing: true,
                    serverSide: true,
                    dom: 'B<"top"frli>tp',
                    ajax: {
                        url: "{{ route('customer.index') }}", //Accessing server for data
                    columns: [
                        {data: 'id'}, //data refers to DB column name
                        {data: 'name'}, 
                        {data: 'chiname'}, 
                        {data: 'type'}, 
                        {data: 'action'}, //this is an addColumn item from Controller
                    ]
                });

        $('#createNewcustomer').click(function () {
                    $('#saveBtn').val("create customer");
                    $('#customerid').val('');
                    $('#customerForm').trigger("reset");
                    $('#modelHeading').html("Create New Customer");
                    $('#customermodal').modal('show');
                });

    //Control the modal behavior when clicking the edit button.
                $('body').on('click', '.editcustomer', function () {
                    var customerid = $(this).data('id');
                    $.get("{{ route('customer.index') }}" +'/' + customerid +'/edit', function (data) {
                        $('#modelHeading').html("Edit Customer");
                        $('#saveBtn').val("edit-user");
                        $('#customermodal').modal('show');
                        $('#customerid').val(data.id);
                        $('#name').val(data.name);
                        $('#chiname').val(data.chiname);
                        $('#type').val(data.type);
                    })
                });

//Create a brand-new record
    $('#createNewcustomer').click(function () {
                    $('#saveBtn').val("create customer");
                    $('#customerid').val('');
                    $('#customerForm').trigger("reset");
                    $('#modelHeading').html("Create New Customer");
                    $('#customermodal').modal('show');
                });

//Update
                $('body').on('click', '.editcustomer', function () {
                    var customerid = $(this).data('id');
                    $.get("{{ route('customer.index') }}" +'/' + customerid +'/edit', function (data) {
                        $('#modelHeading').html("Edit Customer");
                        $('#saveBtn').val("edit-user");
                        $('#customermodal').modal('show');
                        $('#customerid').val(data.id);
                        $('#name').val(data.name);
                        $('#chiname').val(data.chiname);
                        $('#type').val(data.type);
                    })
                });

//Save
    $('#saveBtn').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).html('Sending..');
                $.ajax({
                    data: $('#customerForm').serialize(),
                    url: "{{ route('customer.store') }}",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#customerForm').trigger("reset");
                        $('#customermodal').modal('hide');
                        table.draw();
                        },
                    error: function (data) {
                        console.log('Error:', data);
                        $('#saveBtn').html('Error');}
                });
            });

//Delete
            $('body').on('click', '.deletecustomer', function () {
                var id = $(this).data("id");
                confirm("Are You sure?");
                $.ajax({
                    type: "DELETE",
                    url: "{{ route('customer.store') }}"+'/'+id,
                    success: function (data) {
                        table.draw();
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        console.log('Error:', data);
                    }
                });
            });
</script>
```

View.blade html-table & modal part

```
@section('content')

    <div class="container">
        <div class="card-header border-left"><h3><strong> Customer overview</strong></h3></div>
<br>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md text-right">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" href="javascript:void(0)" id="createNewcustomer">Create Record</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        {{-- Modal --}}
        <div id="customermodal" class="modal fade" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="modelHeading"></h4>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times</span></button></div>
                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <form id="customerForm" name="customerForm" class="form-horizontal">
                            <input type="hidden" name="customerid" id="customerid">

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name" class="col-sm-6 control-label">Customer Name</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" value="" maxlength="50" required="">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                           <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-6 control-label">Customer Name</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="chiname" name="chiname" placeholder="Customer Name" value="" maxlength="50" required="">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                           <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-6 control-label">Contract type</label>
                               <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <select name="type" id="type" class="form-control">
                                                <option value="" disabled>Type</option>
                                                <option value="Government">Government Contract</option>
                                                <option value="Private">Private Contract</option>
                                        </select>
                               </div></div>

                            <br>
                            <div class="col-sm text-right">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" id="saveBtn" value="create">Save changes</button>
                            </div>

                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        {{-- Table --}}
    <br>
        <div class="row">
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <div class="form-group col-md-12 align-content-center">
                <table class="table-fluid center-block" id="customertable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>id</th>
                            <th>ChiName</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Type</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

CustomerController

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
                $customers = Customer::all();
            }
                return Datatables::of($customers)
                    ->addColumn('action', function($customer){
                        $btn = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$customer->id.'" data-original-title="Edit" class="edit btn btn-outline-info btn-sm editcustomer">Edit</a>';
                        $btn = $btn.' <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$customer->id.'" data-original-title="Delete" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm deletecustomer">Delete</a>';
                        return $btn;})
                    ->rawColumns(['action'])
                    ->make(true);
        }
        return view('customer.Customer'); //my view blade is named Customer under customer dir. put your blade destination here.
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        Customer::updateOrCreate(['id' => $request->customerid],
            ['name' => $request->name, 'chiname' => $request->chiname,'type' =>$request->type]);
        return response()->json(['success'=>'Product saved successfully.']);
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        $customer = Customer::findorfail($id);
        return response()->json($customer);
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        Customer::findorfail($id)->delete();
        return response()->json(['success'=>'Product deleted successfully.']);
    }
```

Model (pick either A.) $guarded = [] OR B.) $fillable = ['fields','fields'] as you like)

```
   class Customer extends Model
    {
        protected $fillable = ['name','chiname','type'];
    }
```

web.api (route setting)

```
Route::resource('customer', 'CustomerController')->middleware('auth');
```

Migration / DB schema structure

```
class CreateCustomersTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('chiname');
            $table->string('type');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
   }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('customers');
    }
```

I have not included any protection in it like gate, auth or so. But basically this is the skeleton of doing CRUD with dataTable in Laravel framework with both JS, Ajax, Jquery, PHP all in one. Kindly be reminded that the queries for such CRUD actions are directly linked to the Database server. If you want to show data processed by the DataTable, use your own jquery function to fetch and show them on the modal. My answer is not the best but i hope it helps you >:)

(I could not post a picture to show you here as i dont have enough reputation lol. gg)